# Is it alright to use the phrase "working his butts off" in formal essays such as IELTS?

Tags: colloquial-language

Is it alright to use the phrase "working his butts off" in formal essay writing such as an IELTS exam?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for lack of prior research. It's easy to establish what ***butt*** means in this context, which should make it pretty obvious it's not suitable for formal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that a person has one butt, and so for one person, you should say "working his **butt** off". Note the singular form of butt. If you are talking about several people, of course, you can say "working their butts off".

Second, [butt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butt) is an American slang word meaning bottom. Nice people do not talk about their bottom, or anybody else's, so I would not recommend using the expression in a formal essay.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+butt+off), the idiom:

> **work butt off** = to work very hard: My father worked his backside off to pay for our education

is a very informal American idiom and consequently shouldn't be used in a formal essay.